# Chamar função javascript do CodeBehind enquanto está a correr um processo

Tags: javascript, .net

A ideia é tenho uma grid em que em cada linha existe um botão. O desejado é que quando o utilizador carregue no botão a página fique fixa(freeze) e mande validar o pedido. E quando o servidor retornar o resultado voltar com a página ao estado inicial.

Já tenho o código para fixar e para voltar ao normal com a página. O meu problema é que quando clico no botão de uma das linhas da grid e chamo o método para fixar a página e para processar o pedido ele 1º processa o pedido e depois é que fixa a página. 
O código que estou a usar é o seguinte:

```
protected void gv_parks_ItemCommand(object sender,Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
{ 
   if(e.CommandName == "Process"){
         ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ntmtch", "skm_LockScreen('We are processing your request...');", true);

      int result = ProcessRequest(dados)

      if(result == 0)
      {
           ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ntmtch1", "skm_UnLockScreen('Sucesso...');", true);
      }
      else
      {
          ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ntmtch2", "skm_UnLockScreen('Erro...');", true);
      }
   }
}
```

Alguem sabe como me ajudar? Obrigado